# npm install fails when running through a docker container

Tags: docker, npm

I'm trying to run `npm install` through a docker container, using:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/src cthulhu666/yeoman npm install
```

but it always fails with a message along the lines of the following:

```
85351 error node v5.5.0
85352 error npm  v3.3.12
85353 error path /src/node_modules/.defaults.DELETE/node_modules/clone
85354 error code ENOENT
85355 error errno -2
85356 error syscall rename
85357 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/src/node_modules/.defaults.DELETE/node_modules/clone' -> '/src/node_modules/defaults/node_modules/clone'
85357 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
85357 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I say "along the lines of" because it's not always this file... a couple of days ago when I was trying it was failing on a different file.

I tried on a different machine, using the same package.json and just using the global `npm install` rather than through the docker container and it worked fine, so it seems to be an issue with running it on mounted volumes.

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot this though - whether it's a docker issue, an npm issue or something else altogether...

(just in case it's useful, this is the package.json: https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/package.json)

**Update 1**

I've tried running `docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/src cthulhu666/yeoman /bin/bash` and then running `npm install` in the shell but the same thing happens.

**Update 2**

I forgot to mention... I'm on OSX using docker-machine. The docker-machine VM is VMWare Fusion as the VirtualBox based machines had performance issues. However, I've just tried spinning up the Virtualbox machine and running the command and it completes successfully - so it looks like it is something specific to VMWare Fusion.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Dockerfile where you can issue your npm install then once that creates your image then issue a docker run to launch your processing ? ... just for fun as an alternative in your above docker run command replace npm install with bash then at the interactive terminal prompt manually issue npm install or such where you have more freedom to troubleshoot

Comment: No luck running a /bin/bash shell and then running npm install inside that, I still get the same error. I'm not sure what you mean about creating another Dockerfile...? I've tried creating my own image based on node5-slim but it does the same thing...

Comment: The command npm install only works if the current directory contains a file called :  package.json   ... so when launching with bash do ls -la to show files perhaps you first need to cd into some other directory

Comment: Yes that's true, but I'm in the correct folder. I've updated my question with my latest findings.

Comment: how are you installing node inside docker? can you not use a Node base image? ... FROM node:5.9.1

Comment: I'm using the cthulhu666/yeoman image which is indeed basedon Node... FROM node:5-slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of Docker Native for Mac, the above is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This gives guidance on answering the question.

(1) Try to use node:5.9.1 to rule out any problems with the yeoman image

(2) `RUN` v `ENTRYPOINT`

RUN - `npm install` using `RUN` in your `Dockerfile` does the `npm install` during the Docker build process and saves the node modules inside your image. This is great unless you want to mount the `node_modules` folder. Mounting `node_modules` to the host will overwrite it. Mounting it to another container using `volumes_from` is ok

ENTRYPOINT - `npm install` using `ENTRYPOINT` does the `npm install` as part of the CLI `docker run` command. This is fine when mounting `node_modules`.

(I couldn't work out if you are mounting node_modules).

(3) SIMPLIFY

Also, you might want to remove any packages from your `package.json` which seem to be problematic and reintroduce them one at a time, then you can pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks @danday74, I'll try those points this afternoon. 

It's strange that it works fine on a VirtualBox VM though, or just running NPM install outside of Docker. Would suggest that it's an issue with the VMWareFusion docker machine...